# Is it possible to get all dependencies implementing a certain interface using PHP-DI?

Tags: php, php-di

Using PHP-DI, it is possible to get a dependency using: `$container->get(MyDependency::class)`.

Can I use a similar method to **automatically** get all dependencies implementing a certain interface?

Comment: Yes, you could implement it via Reflections.